# How to solve this NullPointerException? I it should avoid that

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm building an app that uses json data from a server that changes everyday.
Yesterday it worked perfectly. Today, however, i get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

at this line(s) of code:

```
if(!endDate.equals("") && !endDate.equals(null) && !endDate.equals("null")) {
      dates.append(" t/m ").append(endDate);
}
```

To me it seems that the if statement should avoid the nullpointer exception... Do i miss something?

Comment: if(endDate != null) ...

Answer (score 0):

The `endDate` variable is null and you can't call methods on that. These is the reason of the `NullPointerException`.

To avoid the exception, just verify if the variable is not null as the first check if the `if` statement:

```
if(endDate != null && !endDate.equals("")) {
      dates.append(" t/m ").append(endDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all and sorry for the duplicate! It's fixed

Answer (score 0):

It means that your object `endDate` is null.
You should check if you have initialised it somewhere prior to using it.
Also add an if statement prior to your if statements,

```
if(endDate != null){
if(!endDate.equals("") && !endDate.equals("null")) {
      dates.append(" t/m ").append(endDate);
}
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions on why the answer was down-voted would be helpful.

Comment: I totally agree

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, looks like you need to null check the endDate variable itself like this. A method cannot be called on a null object, because basically the method does not exist without an instance.

```
if(endDate != null){
  if(!endDate.equals("") && !endDate.equals(null) && !endDate.equals("null")) {
      dates.append(" t/m ").append(endDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: not a concise implementation I know, but designed to show you the concept more than be optimal

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` means that your `endDate` variable is holding a reference to `null`. Using `.equals()` won't work with nul, because you'd be calling a method on a non-existent (null) object.
You can check for it by using an assert statement (see https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/assert)
Like this: 
`assert (endDate!=null);`

Alternatively, you could just use `if(endDate!=null);`

However, if you actually want to fix things, you should wrap the block in a `try` statement and `catch` any NPE.